# Radius Local Search Algortihm for Max-Sat problem approximating ratio

Tags: satisfiability, approximation, maxsat

Assume that in classical Local Search algorithm for MAX-SAT we could flip no more than $r 
\leq n/2$ variables (let's call it $r$-flip) on every iteration. More precise: on every iteration we're finding $r$-flip which satisfies more clauses then was satisfied before the flip.

What is the approximation ratio of this algorithm? Is there any worst case where my algorithm has multiplicative error 1/2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that the all-zero assignment is a local optimum for your algorithm, for some CNF $\varphi$, say satisfying an $\alpha$ fraction of the clauses. If we choose any assignment of weight at most $n/2$, it should satisfy at most an $\alpha$ fraction of the clauses. In particular, a random assignment of weight exactly $n/2$ satisfies at most an $\alpha$ fraction of clauses.
If we assume that no clauses are empty (empty clauses only work in our favor), then every clause is satisfied with probability at least $1/2$ under this distribution. Hence $\alpha \geq 1/2$, and so your algorithm gives a $1/2$ approximation.

If $\alpha = 1/2$ then all clauses are unit clauses. Since the all-zero assignment is a local optimum, this means that for each variable $x_i$, there must be at least as many clauses $\bar{x}_i$ than clauses $x_i$. Hence the all-zero assignment is actually optimal. This shows that there is no worst case in which the approximation ratio is exactly $1/2$.

Perhaps this gives you a start on finding the actual approximation ratio of your local search algorithm.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but if we say that $r < n/2$ (strictly), then will there be an assigment with approximation ratio exatly 1/2 ? For example if $n$ is odd and $r \leq n/2 \Rightarrow r < n /2$ so we couldn't take a random assignment of weight $n / 2$

Comment: If you change the question, the answer might change. I've given you some hints on how to approach the question, you take it from here.

Comment: I would like to know something about the worst-case in this algorithm,  my bad that I set $r \leq n / 2$, it should be $r < n / 2$ to generalize this algorithm for arbitary n. Can I build the worst case from your answer, or better edit the questing / ask a new one?

Comment: Also, why $\alpha = 1/2$ impies that all clauses are unit clauses? Here is the example for $r = 1$ and $n =3$, where ratio is exact $1/2$. $\varphi = x_1 \vee (\neg x_1 \wedge x_2 \wedge x_3)$, and $(0, 0, 0)$ is a local optimum for $r = 1$ with approximation ratio $1/2$

Comment: Any clause which is not a unit clause is satisfied with probability more than $1/2$ (unless $n$ is very small), which is why $\alpha = 1/2$ is only possible when you have only unit clauses.